# Creating complex data models in yaml front matter in Assemble

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, assemble

Assemble front matter YAML supports dynamic data model creation at the top of a Handlebar page with this syntax

```
 ---
 myModel : { aFile : <%= fileName %>}
 ---

<div>
 {{myModel.aFile.someProperty}}
</div>
```

where fileName is some json file. Is it possible to manipulate myModel in YAML, after creating it, and before it is passed to rendering. This code doesn't work, but I'd like to do something like :

```
 ---
 myModel : { aFile : <%= fileName %>}
 myModel
    aFile
      someProperty : I was set in header 
 ---
```

Failing that, how else could one dynamically generate data in the header? Could I call a custom helper and pass its output to a variable, once again this doesn't work but hypothetically :

```
 ---
 myModel : { data: <%= someHelper('fileName') %> }
 ---
```

Comment: Are you loading data from file with `{ aFile : <%= fileName %>}`, or referencing data loaded by the [Assemble config `data` option](http://assemble.io/docs/options-data.html)?

Comment: Currently, the latter. Is it possible to invoke a file load from yaml front matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do this with a customized Handlebars helper that formats the data however you want.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
assemble: {
    mySite: {
        options: {
            helpers: ['source/helpers/**/*.js']
```

**source/helpers/importJSON.js**

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var _ = require("lodash");
    var fs = require("fs");

    module.exports.register = function(Handlebars, options) {
        Handlebars.registerHelper("importJSON", function(fileSpec, options) {
            var customData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(fileSpec, "utf8"));

            // Do anything to your data here
            if (customData.color === "blue") {
                customData.color = "yellow";
            }

            _.extend(this, customData);
            return "";
        });
    };

}).call(this);
```

**source/templates/somePage.hbs**

```
---
{{importJSON "./source/data/favorite.json"}}
{{log color}}
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Some Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks James, that solved it neatly, with the added bonus of working in partials too - had a few snags trying to get partial YAML to work that way.

Bonus question : do you know if it's at all possible to call a helper from YAML? I haven't seen examples anywhere, so I'm beginning to assume it isn't.

Comment: I don't know how to call a partial or other custom code from YAML lodash templates.  It seems like the templates have access to the site data model, but the results might be limited to strings.  The example in the [Assemble YAML docs](http://assemble.io/docs/YAML-front-matter.html) is fairly simple.